# Google Plugin not working for App Engine project - Eclipse Indigo - WindowsXP

Tags: android, eclipse, google-app-engine

I am trying to run through the [cloud sync tutorial,](http://developer.android.com/training/cloudsync/aesync.html) and for some reason it's not importing Android into the project correctly.  I tried to look at the problem again today and I noticed that there are updates for the Google and Android plugins. I upgraded, and now when I try to load the App Engine connected to Android project wizard, I see the following error:

```
The selected wizard could not be started.
Plug-in "com.google.gdt.eclipse.mobile.android" was unable to instantiate class
"com.google.gdt.eclipse.mobile.android.wizards.NewAndroidCloudProjectWizard".
com/android/io/StreamException
```

Is this a bug with the latest Google plugin?

Comment: Try deleting the workspace , start checkout and project set up from scratch. It might be related to some bad metadata.

Answer (score 1):

I think everyone with the most recent GAE plugin is having the same problem. If you take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11276518/app-engine-connected-android-project-not-available/11382135#11382135) thread, I think it's the same issue.

Long story short, the newest plugin doesn't seem to be compatible with the wizard, which may be because Google is waiting to update it to use GCM instead of [C2DM](https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/).

That's what Google's saying [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-plugin-eclipse/_op9guM5pf4/BArAH-d3TgEJ), and the solution they suggest in the meantime is to create an Android project by itself, right click and go to Google->Generate App Engine Backend... I had some errors when I did this myself, but it might give you some of what you need.