# "App Engine Connected Android Project" not available

Tags: android, eclipse, google-app-engine, eclipse-plugin

According to [this](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/appeng_android_create_project) guide by Google the "App Engine Connected Android Project"
 should be available after installing/configuring ADT plugin for Eclipse, Android SDK and Google Plugin for Eclipse. I have installed everything in the most recent version in both Eclipse 3.7.2 (Indigo) and Eclipse 4.2 (Juno). However, I can't create such a project in any of the two Eclipse releases. Here are my installation details in Juno:

[image: installation details]

And here is a part of my Android SDK details:

[image: SDK details]

My OS is Mac OS X 10.7.4

I know that I could see the menu point on 23/6/2012 before I updated the SDK tools to the most recent version.

Is anyone experiencing a similar issue or does anyone know what I configured the wrong way?

Thanks!

Comment: I suggested this question for the "Android Developers Office Hours (EMEA edition)". See here: https://developers.google.com/live/shows/ahNzfmdvb2dsZS1kZXZlbG9wZXJzcg4LEgVFdmVudBic3IIDDA/
Hopefully this question will be answered then. Please vote up the question using Moderator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found a (I would say semi-official) statement from a Google employee [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-plugin-eclipse/_op9guM5pf4/BArAH-d3TgEJ). It says, that the "App Engine Connected Android Project" has been removed in GPE v3.0.0. It would be possible to downgrade to the last version containing this menu item (2.6.1), which can be downloaded [here](http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/eclipse_toolreleases/products/gpe/release/2.6.1/core/3.7/com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.3.7.update.site_2.6.1.zip).

The reason for the whole migration is, that "C2DM [is now] deprecated and [we] should be using GCM instead". Furthermore

> The official docs [for using GCM] are on the way. In the meanwhile do sign up for the
>   endpoints trusted testers program at
>   http://endpoints-trusted-tester.appspot.com.

They also "plan to add [the menu item] again in the next version of GPE with GCM integrations" and they "plan to release the next version end of July".

Also, I got a similar answer form the Google employee Sparky R.:

> I believe there is a known issue that the template for making
>   GAE-connected Android apps isn't working right now.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it will be helpful, but i have managed to restore the Android SDK tools to rev 19 and Android SDK Platform-tools to rev 11, and installed the Google Plugin from scratch since i don't have the older version of it. It seems i still don't have the option in the menu, so i think it is about the Google Plugin.

In addition, Android Cloud to Device Messaging Framework - C2DM is deprecated since as of June 26, 2012 (https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/). It may be about this deprecation, but it should be more clear in the near future.

Comment: I agree. I guess it has to do something with the migration from C2DM to GCM. And the option in the menu definitely came from the Google plugin. I will try to create two separate projects (an Android project and an App Engine project as a client and a server respectively) to ensure that it is just a bug in the current version of the plugin. I'll report back tomorrow, as it is already quite late here.

Comment: There is an option like "Generate App Engine Backend" when you right click the Android project under the Google menu. I guess the new project option "App Engine Connected Android Application" option replaced by that one..

Comment: I think everyone agrees it's to do with C2DM deprecation so as first to point it out, have 50 rep and welcome to SO!

Answer (score 1):

I've been wasting a lot of time on this.  I had the option in Eclipse 3.7, but now I've upgraded to 4.2 Juno and all the latest other stuff I can no longer see the 'App Engine Connected Android Project' option.  I've had multiple attempts at installing, trying to make sure I get the order right.  I've had major problems with trying to update from within Eclipse, and have had to resort to the various offline options.  Not happy.  How am I supposed to teach this technology when I can't even install it!

Tim

Answer (score 1):

There is an example here, which he creates one of these projects:

http://bradabrams.com/2011/05/google-io-session-overview-android-app-engine-a-developers-dream-combination/

And you can checkout the code:

http://code.google.com/p/cloud-tasks-io/source/checkout

So I'm trying now to strip out what I don't need and get back to basically a new "Appengine Connected Android Project" I don't know how successful that'll be, as I don't know what I need or don't!

Annoying thing is, if this is do to with C2DM, I don't even want to use C2DM. I just want to invoke my app engine app from android, not send messages to android. Maybe I'm going along the wrong lines?

**Edit**

I got my project working (without messages to Android, just Android invoking methods and getting results) using these two examples:

How to call your app: [Android REST client, Sample?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8267928/android-rest-client-sample)

How to access a security enabled app: http://krasserm.blogspot.co.uk/2010/01/accessing-security-enabled-google-app.html

And this to work out how to do the http connection: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

Comment: I already tried to check out the code and import the projects in Eclipse. However, I got some errors saying, that certain libraries they use (basically those having to do with C2DM) are not available. I'm sure this is because of the migration from C2DM to GCM. Anyway, I decided to wait for Google to release a guide how to do it with the new version. If anyone finds a solution sooner, I'd be glad, though.

Comment: @Xtoph.at I ended up finding a couple of examples on how to authenticate and call my google app engine app. No messages pushed to device, but that's all I wanted. If that interests you I can dig out the links when I get home?

Comment: Yes, please post the links when you have time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on windows 7 and I'm also seeing this as well. This had been working for me, then I updated the Android SDK tools to rev 20 and Android SDK Platform-tools to rev 12 (both updated at the same time in the Android SDK Manager) after which I noticed this was not working. I was on Eclipse 3.7 but I upgraded to 4.2 to see if that helped (which I didn't). I then downloaded the Android 4.1 SDK stuff, but that didn't help either.

In addition to "App Engine Connected Android Project" not being ava

Answer (score 0):

This feature is now available for me

Update your Android and App Engine SDKs, and you should be good to go!